# Axios is returning Error: "Network error" when a query is too large

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, axios

I have a query to create agenda based on 2 dates, 2 times, minutes, days of week and some other information that is stored in another table.

So each x minutes I'm storing a row in the agenda table, for each row I'm storing more rows in the other table pointing to the row stored in agenda.

The query works fine to an extent, I'm able to store data but if I want to store agenda for 5 months and above, I get Error: "Network Error" from Axios and my local server stops working so I have to restart it, Telescope is not telling me much other than a request with status 200, and the database won't store anything because I imagine the query is rolled back since it's wrapped in a Laravel transaction helper.

Clearly this is happening due to the "massive" amount of data that is trying to store, but I don't know why, it's not a timeout because I get the error like 8 seconds later and I raised that limit number up to 300 seconds or so in the php config.

```js
createAgenda() {
    Event.$emit('toggle-loading-screen');
    this.errors = [];

    axios.post('createagenda', {
        date_start: this.agendaItem.start,
        date_end: this.agendaItem.end,
        time_start: this.agendaItem.from,
        time_end: this.agendaItem.to,
        valid_days: this.agendaItem.dayList,
        minutes: this.agendaItem.minutes
        entity_ids: this.agendaItem.entityList
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.data.success) {
            Event.$emit('list-dates', false, true);
            if (!response.data.intercepted) {
                this.$emit('check-agenda');
                Event.$emit('simple-modal', response.data.message, false, 0, true);
            } else {
                Event.$emit('simple-modal', response.data.message);
            }
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response.status === 401 || error.response.status === 419) {
            Event.$emit('reload-modal', error.response.data.message);
        } else if (error.response.status === 500) {
            Event.$emit('error-modal', error.response.data.message);
        } else {
            this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            Event.$emit('simple-modal', 'You have validation errors.');
        }
    }).finally(() => { 
        Event.$emit('toggle-loading-screen');
        this.setExtraFlag('false');
    });
},
```

When logging Error, All I get is this:
[image: error]

And this:
[image: error]

I need to know the exact cause of this error so I can prevent it somehow, but I'm honestly expecting to allow people to create agenda for at least 1 year.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at `post_max_size`, `max_input_time`, `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit`.. try to increase them..

Comment: @ZeroOne post_max_size = 64M, max_input_time = 60, max_execution_time = 120, memory_limit = 128M. Second and fourth I should change for sure, gonna report once I test it

Comment: @ZeroOne and yes, that was it, I would assume memory_limit was the issue overall, I fiddled with a bunch of other settings (as you can see with first and third) but I missed that one.
Appreciate the help, if you can make it an answer I can select it